chrome.scripting.executeScript Fails with "Tab Not Found" Error After Creating a New Window in Chrome Extension
I'm developing a Chrome extension and encountering an issue with executing a script in a newly created tab. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
On a button click, I use chrome.windows.create api to open a new popup window. In window I am opening an external webpage.
      // Create the window at the bottom-right corner
      chrome.windows.create({
          url: "https://localhost/index.html", // Replace with your HTML file
          focused: true,
        },
        function (window) {

          tabId = window.id; // Store the ID of the created window

          console.log("Window created at bottom-right corner.", tabId);
          chrome.storage.local.set({
              tabId: tabId
            },
            function () {
              console.log("Popup window ID stored:", tabId);
            }
          );

        });

I am trying to send a message from background.js to https://localhost/index.html using following code

     // This part Working Successfully
    `chrome.windows.update(tabId, {
        focused: true,
     });

`
     chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {
          tabId: tabId
        },
        func: () => {
          window.postMessage(message, '*');
        }
      }, () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(`Script execution failed: ${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}`);
        } else {
          console.log('Message sent to the new window');
        }
     });

chrome.scripting.executeScript, is failing with  Script execution failed. tab not found for id : XXXX error.

I have included necessary permission e.g. tabs, activetab, scripting in v3 manifest file.
I checked if the tab is fully loaded before attempting to execute the script.

I was wondering why am I receiving the "Tab Not Found" error, and how can I ensure that chrome.scripting.executeScript works correctly with newly created window?
My goal is to send message to https://localshot/index.html.


It's window.tabs[0].id 2) Consider using externally_connectable messaging.


@woxxom thanks I was able to fulfil my requirement with externally_connectable messaging. The tab not found issue is still present. It works with normal tab but not when we open pop-up window.
